# How do you convert a standard Android IME to an Android wear IME?

Tags: android, wear-os, ime

making an IME for android wear. i've got a few questions before i go about doing this.

i have a keyboard IME already designed and written.. for Android. (i was told to go ahead and write a normal android IME before using it on android wear)

so, i have this IME and zero idea of where to go next to get it on the android wear. do i just install to my phone and go into development mode and enable the IME on the watch? do i add lines of code somewhere to make it specifically for the android wear?

i know for a fact you can use IMEs on the android wear. there's things everywhere about how to install minuum or whatever and enable input methods on the watch.. my question, are the keyboards for android wear all full-blown SMS apps that just have a keyboard in them as part of the app? do i need to write an SMS app? or will my keyboard just pop up when i hit reply to a text message popup on the watch? (such as the normal popup from the standard android messaging app that comes with the phone.. as currently, hitting reply opens it on the phone, whereas reply with voice lets you talk to it.) or will it bring up another option to reply with an IME?

any help is useful. thanks so much. i know those are probably stupid beginner questions, but i must be overlooking some shred of information somewhere because i'm unable to answer this myself. any relevant links or info would be extremely useful. if any more info is needed, just ask.

Comment: An IME is just another android app, so you can go ahead and install it as normal.  But that doesn't mean the app in question will try and use a keyboard-  if it doesn't now, then it's unlikely to start.  And there's no way to force it to.  So you may well have to replace it.

Comment: so, basically i can sideload my keyboard APK like i would sideload a normal android APK to the android wear?... then enable it via the developer settings and adb? i could sideload anything that uses a text field. this was ssuper helpful and i'd select this as an answer if you wanted to repost this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

IMEs rely on editable text fields, such as made with [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html). You'll note that no included app (nor the vast majority of installable apps) use any editable text fields as there is no concept of a selectable IME on Android Wear (as noted in the [Minuum on Android Wear instructions](http://support.minuum.com/knowledgebase/articles/394385-minuum-on-android-wear)).

Therefore while you could publish and get a IME installed on Android Wear, users would never be able to select the IME (there is no UI) nor would you be able to use it to replace the default reply option (as that is system behavior, not something controlled by the current IME).

Comment: i'm sorry. Minuum exists. also, you can sideload normal apk's like the standard SMS messenger from android to the wear, whilch makes this still a valid question. that and minuum and that group, as t says on their website is trying to push for more text-editable apps. there are not many, but there are some, as it also says on their website.

Comment: I'm not sure how that changes anything I said. Users cannot select an IME via the UI, nor does any of the default UI such as replying from notifications support custom IMEs.

Comment: it doesn't. i'm just saying that wasn't answering my question i appologise. apparently if you sideload apk's from adb with debugging, you can load IMEs like a normal app... and from research i found earlier today, also ith the app called "app2wear" you can sideload normal android apps to the wear as well, thus giving apps that allow for keyboard input with minuum and other keyboards as per normal. snce wear runs on the same OS as android. just stripped down a bunch. thank you for your answer though.

Comment: @KatjaDecuir - as per the instructions on the Minuum site, just installing the IME does not activate it or make it available to apps that have keyboard input - even within Minuum itself, you cannot use the IME until you enable the service with shell commands.

Comment: i believe i addressed that when i mentioned it in the OP and comments of the OP

Comment: So what answer are you looking for then?

Comment: i've installed a standard text messaging app via side loading it to my watch. i can use it with the IME on the watch. that is what i originally wanted to do. didn't know i could just put normal android apps on the watch itself and have it work.(..kinda work)